# I'm still getting the error "ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded!" after more than one month

Tags: python, api, imgur

I'm using the Imgur's API and I'm still getting the error `ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded!` after more than one month. I'm using the official Python library "imgurpython-1.1.7".
Could you please help me to solve this problem? Many thanks in advance.

I read on the official Imgur documentation that "if the daily limit is hit five times in a month, then the app will be blocked for the rest of the month", but in my case more than a month has already passed.

```
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\imgurpython-1.1.7-py3.6.egg\imgurpython\client.py", line 584, in upload_from_path
res = self.upload(fd, config, anon)
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\imgurpython-1.1.7-py3.6.egg\imgurpython\client.py", line 599, in upload
return self.make_request('POST', 'upload', data, anon)
File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\imgurpython-1.1.7-py3.6.egg\imgurpython\client.py", line 153, in make_request
 raise ImgurClientRateLimitError()
imgurpython.helpers.error.ImgurClientRateLimitError: Rate-limit exceeded!
```